# ruby rake rspec ci_reporter_rspec prevents multiple output formats from being generated

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake

I am trying to integrate this gem https://github.com/ci-reporter/ci_reporter_rspec in to my rake task below to output the following formats:

- `progress`: on screen during run
- `documentation`/`html`: separate files. `"test/reports/spec.txt"` & `"test/reports/spec.html"` respectively
- `xunit`: generates files from ci_reporter_rspec

The `progress` format displays on screen, the `xunit` files are generated but `documentation` and `html` files are not generated. I can confirm when ci_reporter_rspec is not included then it works as design minus `xunit` files. I need all formats generated, can anyone see what I'm missing?

---

```
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'
require 'ci/reporter/rake/rspec'

RSpec::Core:RakeTask.new(:spec => ['ci:setup:rspec']) do |t|
  t.rspec_opts = '--format progress --format documentation -o "test/reports/spec.txt" --format html -o "test/reports/spec.html"'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in ci-reporter since the same problem happens for me. But, when I remove CI reporter this works just fine. I have opened an issue [here](https://github.com/ci-reporter/ci_reporter_rspec/issues/14).